# switch text and image depending on user's input

Tags: javascript, svg

I am just starting with HTML,JS and I am trying to switch both text and image depending on user's input. The idea is to use user's answers as trigger events to change images (external svg files) and text (switch case for each Note). That what I have so far:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<input id="UserInputText" type="text" value="A">
<input id="UserInputImage" type="image" value="A">

<p id="demo1"></p>
<p id="demo2"></p>

<script>
var text;
var image;
var answers = document.getElementById("myInputText").value;
var answers = document.getElementById("myInputImage").value;

switch(answers) {
case "A":
    text = "NoteA";
    image=<img src="image_library/grandstaff_drawing.svg"></img>;
    break;
case "B":
    text = "NoteB";
    image=<img src="image_library/grandstaff_drawing1.svg"></img>;
    break;
case "C":
    text = "NoteC";
    image=<img src="image_library/grandstaff_drawing2.svg"></img>;
    break;
case "D":
    text = "NoteD";
    image=<img src="image_library/grandstaff_drawing3.svg"></img>;
    break;  
case "E":
    text = "NoteE";
    image=<img src="image_library/grandstaff_drawing4.svg"></img>;
    break;  
case "F":
    text = "NoteF";
    image=<img src="image_library/grandstaff_drawing5.svg"></img>;
    break;  
case "G":
    text = "NoteG";
    image=<img src="image_library/grandstaff_drawing6.svg"></img>;
    break;  
default:
    text = "I have never heard of that note";
}
document.getElementById("demo1").innerHTML = text;
document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML = image;

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Thank you!!!

Comment: for starters, you have 2 variables with the same name 'answers'. Also, I'm not sure if you can have an `img` tag inside a `p` tag

Comment: In addition to what @AbdulAhmad said, input type='image' is an image that you click on to get coordinates, e.g. x and y coords where the user clicked. Is that what you want? Maybe describe your functional goals in more detail.

Comment: You need single quotes around all the `'<img ... ></img>'`.

Comment: The IDs in the HTML are "UserInputText" and "UserInputImage", but in JavaScript "myInputText" and "myInputImage" are respectively called. This won't work. The variable "answers" (``var answers``) gets redefined immediately, so the first assignment is lost.

Answer (score 1):

I've updated your code in [this fiddle to demo](http://jsfiddle.net/147jcpku/). Take a look at it and the javascript. Here's the code if you want to just view it here:

html

```
<input id="UserInputImage" type="text" value="A"/>
<div class='button' onclick="change()">click</div>

<div id="demo1"></div>
<div id="demo2"></div>
```

css

```
.button {
    padding: 5px 10px;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: inline;
}
```

javascript

```
function change() {
var text = "";
var image = "";
//alert('hi');
var answers = document.getElementById("UserInputImage").value;
    //alert(answers);
switch(answers) {
case "A":
    text = "NoteA";
    image='<img src="http://smallbeerpress.com/wp-content/uploads/itunes.png"></img>';
    break;
case "B":
    text = "NoteB";
    image='<img src="http://fc01.deviantart.net/fs29/f/2009/238/d/8/Small_50x50__png_clock_pic_by_counter_countdown_ip.png"></img>';
    break;
case "C":
    text = "NoteC";
    image='<img src="http://a.deviantart.net/avatars/r/a/rachelsrandomart.gif?12"></img>';
    break;

default:
    text = "I have never heard of that note";
}
document.getElementById("demo1").innerHTML = text;
document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML = image;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to do some changes in your code to achieve what you want.
First, you can't assign the same var name to two different values, so, avoid:

```
var answers = document.getElementById("myInputText").value;
var answers = document.getElementById("myInputImage").value;
```

Next, you need to listen to an event and assign it to a function, in this case, the event you are looking for is called "change", and you need to use an event listener.

And last, all your strings needs to be inside quotes, you can use single quotes like this:

```
image="<img src='image_library/grandstaff_drawing4.svg'></img>";
```

Or, escape the quotes, like this:

```
image="<img src=\"image_library/grandstaff_drawing4.svg\"></img>";
```

Or better, you can only set the source and assign it to an img tag in the dom.

Try the next code:

```
<input id="UserInputText" type="text" value="A">
<input id="UserInputImage" type="text" value="A">
<p id="demoText"></p>
<img id="demoImg">
<script>
var text;
var image;
var inputTxt = document.getElementById("UserInputText");
var inputImg = document.getElementById("UserInputImage");

inputTxt.addEventListener('change',changeContent);
inputImg.addEventListener('change', changeContent);

function changeContent() {
    var txtValue = inputTxt.value;
    var imgValue = inputImg.value;
    switch(txtValue){
        //...
        case "C":
            text = "NoteC";
        break;
        //...
    }
    switch(imgValue){
        //...
        case "C":
            image = " http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/8/86/TUX-G2-SVG.svg/610px-TUX-G2-SVG.svg";
        break;
        //...
    }
    p = document.getElementById("demoText");
    i = document.getElementById("demoImg");
    p.innerHTML = text;
    i.src = image;
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% sure of what you're trying to accomplish, but I'll answer from the point of view of a person thinking you're trying to switch text and images based on which note is clicked. Try this:
**Note. You need to use the [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) JavaScript library**

HTML:

`<html><body><img src="imagesrc.png" id='NoteA'><img src="imagesrc2.png" id='NoteB'><p id='text'>Text goes here</p> <img src="note.svg" id='image'></body></html>`

JS:

```
var text=document.getElementById('text');
var image=document.getElementById('image');
var notes = [document.getElementById('NoteA'), document.getElementById('NoteB')]; // just doing two for simplicity
function switchToNoteInfo(note){
    if (note=='a') {
        $(text).value('Your text for note A');
        $(image).attr('src', 'image_library/grandstaff_drawing6.svg') //or put your own src for note A
    else if (note=='b') {
        $(text).value('Your text for note B');
        $(image).attr('src', 'image_library/grandstaff_drawing6.svg') //or put your own src for note b
    }
}
$(notes[0]).click(function() {switchToNoteInfo('a')});
$(notes[1]).click(function() {switchToNoteInfo('b')});
```

Comment: Thank you all for prompt and explicit feedback. I used your comments to fix my code. It works now. I really appreciate your kind support and patience with amateur's errors.